# expanding and shrinking of divs using javascript

Tags: javascript

For an application I am designing, the need is as follows. I have a div-wrapper that contains 2 divs,one on the top and another at the bottom respectively. The requirement is when i click on a link in the top div, the div should expand vertically such that the bottom div should shrink to a considerable amount.Similarly,when a link in the bottom div is clicked,the div should expand such that the top div shinks to a considerable amount. Could anyone guide me as to how to approach this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have an example of the described markup?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

```
My sample html code is as follows,
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="class1">
<a href="#" onclick="toggleClass(this);">more</a>
</div>
<div class="class2">
<a href="#" onclick="toggleClass(this);">more</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>


The CSS:
.class1
{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:red;
}
.class2
{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:blue;
}
.class3
{
width:300px;
height:600px;
background-color:red;
}
.class4
{
width:300px;
height:600px;
background-color:blue;
}

The JS code: Just toggle if it is class 1 or class 2 
function toggleClass(el){
    if(el.className == "class1"){
        el.className = "class3";
    } else {
        el.className = "class4";
    }
}

The toggle effect is not happening. Could people please guide me where im going wrong?
```